# Complexity of inbuilt function used in Python3 to compute pow(a,b)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Will the function that uses iteration and the fact that
*a<sup>n</sup> = (axa)<sup>n/2</sup>* when n is even & *[(axa)<sup>(n-1)/2</sup>]xa* when n is odd
yield better results than the inbuilt function in python 3.

Comment: Quick answer would be: No, you will *never* be able to beat the efficiency of built-in functions. Especially not if you are using recursion, which is especially costly since Python has no tail-recursion.

Comment: I already stated that I am using iteration .

Comment: Sorry I misread that, but the answer is still no, you will not be able to beat Python's built-in, especially arithmetic. I'd write and answer, but I believe a benchmark would be fun to do and I am sure someone will take the time to do so.

The simple fact that your are instantiating new integer object at every iteration is extremely costly. Python objects, even integers, are fairly big.

Comment: Where can I find the exact function that python uses to computer pow(a,b) ?

Comment: I believe it is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9b6c60cbce4ac45e8ccd7934babff465e9769509/Objects/floatobject.c
line 685. As you see, you cannot beat the C implementation with a Python implementation.

Comment: Since we are going down the Python implementation rabbit hole, I took the time to write an answer.

Comment: What is better in this context? Faster? Why don't you write a program with `timeit` and tell us the result for both cases? [You can answer your own questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not be able to out perform Python built-in operations. The reason is fairly simple, those built-in operations run C code, in the case of CPython. You will not beat C code by writing Python code.

If we think about your case specifically, your solution would require to instantiate multiple integer or float objects, do comparions, multiply, *all that in Python*! This is something the built-in *power* operator does not do, as Python has an instruction that computes the power in C and only instantiate one object, which is the value that you want.

We can see that by using `dis` to see python bytecode.

```
>>> import dis    
>>> dis.dis('a**b')
1         0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
          2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
          4 BINARY_POWER
          6 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis("""
r = 1
while b > 1:
    if b % 2:
        b = (b - 1) / 2
        a *= a
        r *= a
    else:
        b /= 2
        a *= a
r *= a""")

2         0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
          2 STORE_NAME               0 (r)

3         4 SETUP_LOOP              66 (to 72)
          6 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
          8 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
         10 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
         12 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       70

4        14 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
         16 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
         18 BINARY_MODULO
         20 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       52

5        22 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
         24 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
         26 BINARY_SUBTRACT
         28 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
         30 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
         32 STORE_NAME               1 (b)

6        34 LOAD_NAME                2 (a)
         36 LOAD_NAME                2 (a)
         38 INPLACE_MULTIPLY
         40 STORE_NAME               2 (a)

7          42 LOAD_NAME                0 (r)
         44 LOAD_NAME                2 (a)
         46 INPLACE_MULTIPLY
         48 STORE_NAME               0 (r)
         50 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6

9        52 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
         54 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
         56 INPLACE_TRUE_DIVIDE
         58 STORE_NAME               1 (b)

10       60 LOAD_NAME                2 (a)
         62 LOAD_NAME                2 (a)
         64 INPLACE_MULTIPLY
         66 STORE_NAME               2 (a)
         68 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
         70 POP_BLOCK

 11      72 LOAD_NAME                0 (r)
         74 LOAD_NAME                2 (a)
         76 INPLACE_MULTIPLY
         78 STORE_NAME               0 (r)
         80 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
         82 RETURN_VALUE
```

I'll let you guess how disproportionately more efficient the built-in is.